# How to use Google Docs on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: google, google-drive

How to use Google Docs on a desktop? So when say I click an 'xlsx' file it opens with Google docs. Of course, I can upload the file to GD and then edit it, but is there a way to open files with GD by default?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details  (*your last off-topic deleted question & the swearing you replaced it with make your username rather easy to recall*)

Comment: While I cannot personally vouch for it, see the availability of a Google Docs snap here: https://snapcraft.io/google-docs. However, as others have already indicated, Google Docs is a web-based productivity suite, so local editing is not a design consideration.

Comment: What @richbl has posted is a snap that is just a really cool front end for Google Docs, but it is still running on the web and requires a connection to the web for it to work.  Unfortunately, it cannot open local files either as it still requires the files to be uploaded first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it since Google Docs is web only for PCs.  There is an extension for it that you can install into Chrome to help, but it will only allow for you to edit your files offline that are already up in Google Drive that you make available for offline.  There is no way to make any of your local files to be opened by Google Docs without uploading them first.  If you would like this feature I would suggest contacting Google about it and asking them to make their apps available for installation in any OS.

Answer (score 0):

Google docs is web-based. There is no software for it. You have to use it from your browser. I did before and it worked perfectly fine, the same way you'd do on any other OS. Like Terrance said, you'll have to upload the file through Google docs if it's a local one, or create it on the cloud.